# AnyDice: semantics of output headers in "export" view

Tags: anydice

I hope this is on-topic: In AnyDice, when choosing the "Export" view, `output d6` is displayed as:

```
"output 1",3.5000000000069997,1.707825127661641,1,6
#,%
1,16.6666666667
2,16.6666666667
3,16.6666666667
4,16.6666666667
5,16.6666666667
6,16.6666666667
```

I'm not quite sure what the numbers in the first line signify, the last two (1 and 6) are presumably the range of values that the rolls can take on but what about the other two (3.5 and 1.7...)? I have not been able to figure this out from the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The four numbers after the name of the output are the **mean, standard deviation, minimum and maximum** of the distribution. You will often see the first two of them shown on other forms of output, often written as `(3.50 / 1.71)`. You'll see all four items as their own outputs on the "Summary" data tab (so you can compare averages between several different distributions).